# BeautifulSoup with div tag and no attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape data from a webpage:

There will be multiple results in the html , looking for most efficient way using find_all to retrieve items in div and span tags, 
the only thing I can that makes each entry different is `/results?phoneno=999999999&amp;rid=0x0`.

It'll have a rid=0x0 rid=0x1 etc.. not sure how to grab all these elements listed below

```
<div class="card-summary" data-detail="/results?phoneno=999999999&amp;rid=0x0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="h4">Kevin Johnson</div>
            <div>
                 <span class="content-label">Age </span>
                 <span class="content-value">54 </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                 <span class="content-label">Lives in </span>
                 <span class="content-value">Las Vegas, NV</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-summary" data-detail="/results?phoneno=6666666666&amp;rid=0x02">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="h4">Amy Smith</div>
            <div>
                <span class="content-label">Age </span>
                <span class="content-value">25 </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="content-label">Lives in </span>
                <span class="content-value">New York, NY</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i.e: `["Kevin Johnson", "54", "Las Vegas, NV", "/results?phoneno=999999999&amp;rid=0x0"]`

for each person into list then output it to print
like `data = [["Name","Age","Location","URL"]]`

Comment: So… what's the question here? The most efficient way to `find_all` all div tags is to `find_all` all div tags; there isn't really any alternative that meets that requirement. Also, is "the most efficient way" really a requirement in the first place?

Comment: can you include the code or a script you did untill now

Comment: sorry html didnt post correctly the first time, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dictionary for each person with keys for `name`, `age`, `contact`, `lives_in`. Find these details for each person and then append these dictionaries in a list.

Code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
information = []
for person in soup.find_all('div', class_='card-summary'):
    person_info = {}
    person_info['contact'] = person['data-detail']
    person_info['name'] = person.find('div', class_='h4').text
    person_info['age'] = person.find('span', text='Age ').find_next('span').text
    person_info['location'] = person.find('span', text='Lives in ').find_next('span').text
    information.append(person_info)

print(information)
```

Output:

```
[{'age': '54 ',
  'contact': '/results?phoneno=999999999&rid=0x0',
  'location': 'Las Vegas, NV',
  'name': 'Kevin Johnson'},
 {'age': '25 ',
  'contact': '/results?phoneno=6666666666&rid=0x02',
  'location': 'New York, NY',
  'name': 'Amy Smith'}]
```

---

If you want the information in a list, you can use this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
information = []
for person in soup.find_all('div', class_='card-summary'):
    contact = person['data-detail']
    name = person.find('div', class_='h4').text
    age = person.find('span', text='Age ').find_next('span').text
    location = person.find('span', text='Lives in ').find_next('span').text
    information.append([name, age, location, contact])

print(information)
```

Output:

```
[['Kevin Johnson', '54 ', 'Las Vegas, NV', '/results?phoneno=999999999&rid=0x0'], ['Amy Smith', '25 ', 'New York, NY', '/results?phoneno=6666666666&rid=0x02']]
```

Comment: @inc0gnit0c0de, if you need explanation for any part, feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you quick response. when i try to print it prints some data then i get: ValueError: too many values to unpack, also how do i extract the data from the html to out to print? im new to python and beautifulsoup

Comment: If the HTML that you're running the code on isn't consistent with the HTML you've provided, it will raise those errors. And, what do you mean by *how do i extract the data from the html to out to print*?

Comment: @inc0gnit0c0de, please check the edited code. I've made some changes. It shouldn't give any errors now.